# Unable to get controller to post comments - AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to get PostsCtrl controller to display comments I have in the addPost function that is in the MainCtrl.  My goal is to be able to post the comments (in the right pane) associated with a post (in the left pane).  Did I not initialize something, or is there something missing in my addComment function?

```
---
name: home
url: /
---
<br>
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-block">
      <div class="grid-block">

        <div id="chatBlock" class="small-12 medium-8 grid-content medium-order-1">
          <div class="card">
            <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'" class="card-section">
              <a ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"><img zf-iconic="" icon="thumb" size="medium"></a>
              <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                {{post.title}}
              </a>
              <span ng-hide="post.link" class="">
                {{post.title}}
              </span> | <span ng-model="post.upvotes">upvotes: </span><span class="success badge">{{post.upvotes}}</span>
              <span>
                  <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        <br>
        <form ng-submit="addPost(post)">
          <input type="text" ng-model="post.title" placeholder="Add post..."></input>
          <br>
          <input type="text" ng-model="post.link" placeholder="Add link..."></input>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="large button">Post</button>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-block">
        <div id="contacts" class="small-12 medium-4 grid-content medium-order-2">
          <div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">

            <div class="page-header">
              <h3>
                <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                  {{post.title}}
                </a>
                <span ng-hide="post.link">
                  {{post.title}}
                </span>
              </h3>
            </div>

            <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
                ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)">+</span>
              {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
              <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">{{comment.body}}</span>
            </div>

            <form ng-submit="addComment()">
              <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="body"></input>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
    (function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('chatter', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',

    //foundation
    'foundation',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting.animations'
  ])
    .factory('posts', [function(){
      var o = {
        posts: []
      };
      return o;
    }])
    .config(config)
    .run(run)

    // inject posts service into main controller
    .controller('MainCtrl', [
      '$scope', 'posts',
      function($scope, posts){
        // bind $scope.posts to posts array in factory
        $scope.posts = posts.posts;
        $scope.body = posts.body;
        $scope.test = 'Comments';

        $scope.addPost = function(post){
          if(!post.title || post.title === '') { return; } 
          if(!post.upvotes) { post.upvotes = 0 } 
          $scope.posts.push({
            title: post.title, 
            link: post.link,
            upvotes: post.upvotes,
            comments: post.comments,
            comments: [
              {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
              {author: 'Todd', body: 'This is a crappy post!', upvotes: 2}
            ]
          });
          post.title = '';
          post.link = '';
        };
        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
          post.upvotes += 1;
        };
    }])
    // Posts controller
    .controller('PostsCtrl', [
      '$scope',
      '$stateParams',
      'posts',
      function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
        $scope.posts.comments = posts.posts.comments;

        $scope.addComment = function(comment){
          if(!comment.body === '') { return; }
          $scope.comments.push({
            body: comment.body,
            author: 'user',
            upvotes: 0
          });
          comment.body = '';
        };
    }])

  config.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];

  function config($urlProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlProvider.otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled:false,
      requireBase: false
    });

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  }

  function run() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
  }

})();
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing with the above code?  Any error messages in your console?

Comment: The error I get in the console is:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.addComment (http://localhost:8080/assets/js/app.js:61:22)

This would be the 2nd line in the addComment() function:

if(!comment.body === '') { return; }

Comment: It seems that the problem is that the .comment property is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `addComment` without passing in a variable as the first parameter here:

```
<form ng-submit="addComment()">
```

But the `addComment` function expects a parameter:

```
$scope.addComment = function(comment){
    if(!comment.body === '') { return; }
            // ^^^^^ undefined because you didn't pass it in.
```

Instead, you should change `addComment` to look at the data that is on the scope that is being modified by the inputs.

Update the template input to look something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="comment.body"></input>
```

Then just look on the scope:

```
$scope.comment = {};
$scope.addComment = function(){
    if(!this.comment.body === '') { return; }
```

Comment: I should have stated that MainCtrl is being used in the body of index.html and this is an included page (home.html).

Comment: That helps, Stephen...I'm now getting that .body is undefined.

Comment: That gets me further, but I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" when I try to push the comment to the comments array.

Comment: Ah, looks like I didn't define an empty array in the scope.  Now I can push the comments fine.  Thanks for your help, Stephen.